# OpenGL ES 2.0 software library

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have an application written on embedded device which is running on OpenGL ES 2.0. I want to debug issues with the application using PC . Currently My PC is running Ubuntu 11.04 and it doesnt have any Graphics card. 
For the purpose of debugging , I want to have any software based OpenGL ES2.0 libraries. Is there any such libraries preset? If so can any one provide me a link?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have emulator from ARM AMD and Imagination Technologies to run opengl es 2.0 on windows/ubuntu.

I suggest going with Imagination technologies one.

here is the link http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp